# Bootstrap selectpicker selected items format

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I have multiple selectpicker and i dont understand how to change selected items format. Any suggestions guys?

[image]

I read [this](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/) and found option **selectedTextFormat** but that's not what i need

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    selectedTextFormat: 'values'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found sollution

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        showSubtext: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
    <option data-subtext="Mustard" value="">1</option>
    <option data-subtext="Ketchup">2</option>
    <option data-subtext="Relish">3</option>
</select>
```